# Android/ Laravel: Save User Info on Server Not Working

Tags: java, android, laravel, backend

I use android app and try to save user info on a laravel API backend but It returns with the following error:

```
E/Volley: [1206] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for 

https://starone.magossa.com/api/save_user_info
W/System.err: com.android.volley.ServerError
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:205)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:131)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
```

The method I use is called : saveUserInfo() and I save 3 fields: name, lastname, photo and here is the code for it:

```
private void saveUserInfo(){
    dialog.setMessage("Loading");
    dialog.show();
    String name = txtName.getText().toString().trim();
    String lastName = txtLastname.getText().toString().trim();

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constant.SAVE_USER_INFO, response->{

        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
            if(object.getBoolean("success")){
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userPref.edit();
                editor.putString("photo", object.getString("photo"));
                editor.apply();
                startActivity(new Intent(UserInfoActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        dialog.dismiss();

    }, error->{
        error.printStackTrace();
        dialog.dismiss();
    }) {
        //add token to headers

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            String token = userPref.getString("token", "");
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("Authorization", "Bearer" +token);
            return map;
        }


        //add Params

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("name", "name");
            map.put("lastname", "lastname");
            map.put("photo", bitmapToString(bitmap));
            return map;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(UserInfoActivity.this);
    queue.add(request);
}
```

The registration and login operations are working smoothly .. Can someone tell me what is wrong in the code

This how I implement saveUserInfo by clicking the button:

```
 btnSave.setOnClickListener(v->{
        if (validate()){
            saveUserInfo();
        }
    });
```

and here is Laravel backend part:

```
public function saveUserInfo(Request $request){
    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->lastname = $request->lastname;
    $photo = '';
    //check if user provided photo
    if($request->photo != ''){
        //user time for photo name to prevent name duplicate
        $photo = time().'.jpg';
        //decode photo string and save to storage/profiles
        file_put_contents('storage/profiles/'.$photo, base64_decode($request->photo));
        $user->photo = $photo;
    }
    $user->update();

    return response()->json([
        'success'=>true,
        'photo'=>$photo,
    ]);
}
```

and this is the Route for it:

```
Route::post('save_user_info','Api\AuthController@saveUserInfo')->middleware('jwtAuth');
```

Comment: And how is your client-side Java code related to the server-side error code?

Comment: @MartinZeitler I edited the code and added the part which connects me to the backend